# Asp.net user control with inner controls

Tags: asp.net, web-user-controls

I need to develop a template-like user control, which would accept any arbitrary content, including other controls.

**WmlCard.ascx**

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="phContent" runat="server">
<card id="<%= Me.CardId %>" title="<%= Me.Title %>"> 
<p>
    <%= Me.InnerText %>
</p>
</card>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

It would be used this way:
**ListaTelefonica.aspx**

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="sic" TagName="Card" Src="~/path/to/WmlCard.ascx"%>    
<sic:Card ID="BuscaCard" runat="server" CardId="busca" title="Lista Telefônica" Visible="false">
   <asp:Literal ID="SomeLiteral" runat="server" Visible="false">Some text<br /></asp:Literal>
   <asp:Literal ID="RuntimeFilledLiteral" runat="server" Visible="false" /><br /></asp:Literal>
   Any text.
</sic:Card>
```

---

It is unfortunate that Ascx user controls have to inherit `System.Web.UI.UserControl`. If I could inherit `System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl`, for example, it would be a piece of cake.

My problem is similar [to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551372/accessing-inner-value-of-asp-net-web-user-control), but instead of just text the control should accept any other control inside it.

---

I tried `<ParseChildren(False)>` and overriding `AddParsedSubObject(Object)` in `WmlCard`, but it is not a solution because the html is rendered before the Page Load, making it pointless to change the value of `RuntimeFilledLiteral.Text` in a page's Page_Load, for example.

First error I got:
*Parser Error Message: Type* 'ASP.sic_sicphone_usercontrol_wmlcard_ascx' *does not have a public property named 'Literal'.*

After adding `<PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerDefaultProperty), ParseChildren(True, "InnerText")>`:
*The 'InnerText' property of 'sic:Card' does not allow child objects.*

Same as above but changing WmlCard's property `InnerText` type from `String` to `List(Of Object)`:
*Literal content ('Any text.') is not allowed within a 'System.Collections.IList'.*

After adding `<ParseChildren(False)>` and overriding `AddParsedSubObject`:
No error message, but WmlCard's content is rendered to html before I have a chance to change its inner controls runtime properties.

If I change WmlCard to inherit `System.Web.UI.WebControls.PlaceHolder` instead of `System.Web.UI.UserControl`:
*'...UserControl.WmlCard' is not allowed here because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.UserControl'.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a valid way:

1) Put nothing inside my control (WmlCard.ascx).

2) Added the attribute `<ParseChildren(False)>` to WmlCard.

3) Added a handler to the event PreRender on WmlCard:

```
Private Sub Page_PreRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
  Dim litBefore As New Literal()
  litBefore.Text = String.Format("<card id=""{0}"" title=""{1}""><p>", Me.CardId, Me.Title)

  Dim litAfter As New Literal()
  litAfter.Text = "</p></card>"

  Me.Controls.AddAt(0, litBefore)
  Me.Controls.Add(litAfter)
End Sub
```

And that's it. Everything is working. Thanks for your help thinking thru this!

Comment: I noticed that my sic:Card control (WmlCard) cannot directly contain `<%# %>` or <%= %>` tags. An easy workaround is to enclose such contents inside an Asp:Placeholder (or any other control).

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a templated user control.

Take a look at this article for a detailed how-to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36574bf6.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you could create a custom user control, inherit from placeholder and your problem should be solved?

You can go the templated control way as suggested but I don't see the reason why you would want to do that.

```
 [SupportsEventValidation, DefaultEvent("YourEventName")]
    [ParseChildren(true)]
    [PersistChildren(false)]
    [ToolboxBitmap(typeof(System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel))]
    public class MyCustomControl : System.Web.UI.WebControls.PlaceHolder, INamingContainer, IPostBackDataHandler, IPostBackEventHandler
```

you can override the Render method to control the rendered HTML. I am struggling to see youru actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Got this working simply enough.

```
[ParseChildren(false)]
public class CssControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        string html = null;
        using(var innerWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter())
        using(var htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(innerWriter))
        {
            base.Render(htmlWriter);
            html = innerWriter.GetStringBuilder().ToString();               
        }

        var min = ScriptAndCssParser.MinifyCssFromHtml(html);
        writer.Write(min);
    }
}
```

In my case my goal was allow a master page level control to have child HTML and server-controls, like `asp:content` blocks. That way Viewpages could pass stylesheets up the chain to the master page.

Then I wanted to intercept all the generated HTML, and minify the CSS files. The minification part is out of scope for this question, but the above `ParseChildren(false)` prevents the "element can't contain..." error in the .aspx, and then calling `base.Render()` on an inner writer allows you to use the existing Web Forms pipeline to do all the rendering for you of both server-controls and plain HTML content.